# NgRx8: runtimeChecks cause properties to trigger early

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I've added the immutability checks in the reducer, just activating one:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
  runtimeChecks: {
    strictStateImmutability: true,
    // strictActionImmutability: true,
    // strictStateSerializability: true --> Sucks, f.e. can't serialize objects
    // strictActionSerializability: true, --> Sucks too
  },
}),
```

Nothing too fancy here, but it seems like as soon as any of the runtimeChecks is set to true, the store traps ANY properties, not just the ones in the state.

For example, I have a small login component:

```
  public formGroup: FormGroup;
  public isLoggingIn = false;

  public constructor(
    private formGroupBinder: RxFormGroupBindingService,
    private formBuilder: LogInFormBuilderService,
    private store: Store<IAppState>) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.buildFormGroup();
  }

  public logIn(): void {
    this.isLoggingIn = true;
    const request = new LoginRequest();
    this.formGroupBinder.bindToModel(this.formGroup, request);
    this.store.dispatch(new LogInAction(request));
  }

  public get canLogIn(): boolean {
    console.log('canLogIn: ' + !!this.formGroup);
    return !this.formGroup.invalid && !this.isLoggingIn;
  }
```

As soon as the store strict check is activated, the "canLogin" property is called before the ngOnInit, causing a "formgroup is undefined" error. The console shows this:

[image]

Interesting enough, I didn't find much of a hint regarding the immutability checks. Is there something wrong in the code or am I just loosing the safety of the component lifecycle hooks?